If Psalm 110 was NOT written by David, then did Jesus make an error in stating that "David himself calls him [the messiah] 'lord'" in the Psalm?
If Psalm 110 was NOT written by David, then did Jesus make an error in stating that "David himself calls him [the messiah] 'lord'" in the Psalm (Mark 12:36-37; Mat. 22:43-45; Luke 20:42-44), or is there a better way of looking at this?
I've read a few commentaries (expositional and scholarly) on the New Testament passages and Psalm in question (Expositor's Bible Commentary: Carson (Matthew), Wessel and Strauss (Mark), Liefeld and Pao (Luke), VanGemeren (Psalms); Word Biblical Commentary: Evans (Mark), Hagner (Matthew), Nolland (Luke), Allen (Psalms 101-150); and the NET Bible's notes to name a few). At least one of the Expositor's commentators recommended Allen's commentary. I agree that his appears to provide the most thorough analysis of the Psalm's original context of the commentaries I've read and also best addresses the question at hand. While he concludes that the Psalm was most likely written about David, not by David (as also the NET concludes), he also writes, "An understanding of the heading of the psalm in terms of Davidic authorship features twice in argumentation, at Mark 12:35–37 (and parallels) and Acts 2:33. This understanding, already as old in principle as the redactional characterization of the block of Davidic psalms in Pss 3–71 as “the prayers of David son of Jesse” in Ps 72:20, accords with what R. N. Longenecker has called the “circumstantial” or “descriptive” type of interpretation, based on ancient cultural norms, to be found in the NT, as distinct from the normative kind of exegesis practiced today (TynBul 21 [1970] 36–38; Biblical Exegesis, 193–98)."
I've since read some of the recommended book by Longenecker, Biblical Exegesis in the Apostolic Period, learning much about Jewish exegetical practices around the 1st century. I also read Dr. Michael Brown's take on Jesus' use of Psalm 110 in his book, Answering Jewish Objections to Jesus, Vol. 3. While he prefers defending the Psalm originally being written about the Messiah, he also concedes,
"Even if the psalm was originally written by a court poet for his lord, King David, it would still point to David’s priestly calling (as a prototype of the Messiah) as well as to his worldwide reign, fulfilled only through David’s greater descendant, King Messiah. This would mean, then, that Jesus was pointing to Jewish interpretation of the day, interpretation that attributed the authorship of this psalm to David, thereby proving that Messiah had to be greater than David, but without making a definitive statement about the authorship of the psalm."
This is the best and most direct answer I've found so far. The difficulty now is reconciling the assumption that Jesus was not "making a definitive statement about the authorship of the psalm" with the language that he uses, which appears to be definitive. Matthew's version seems to be most easily reconciled with this approach, since Davidic authorship is merely an assumed part of Jesus' questions to his opponents. Mark and Luke are more difficult, Mark's version reading, "David himself said by the Holy Spirit,... David himself calls him 'Lord'." (I also explored the possibility that David could merely be a colloquial designation for the Davidic Psalms, attempting to replace David with the Davidic author in Jesus' quote. This, however, doesn't seem to work well, since  the argument in the gospels revolves around the question of how the messiah could be David's son, whenever David, the assumed author of the Psalm, calls him 'Lord'.)
I also have some deeper questions, which I think are pertinent to how we answer the main question: Does Jesus himself believe that David wrote the psalm? (It's easier to account for other New Testament writers' use of Jewish tradition, since they aren't themselves divine.) If so, how should that inform our Christology? (Which part of His argument is divine and which part is human?) Is the point Jesus tries to make undermined if his argument is based on a false premise? If Jesus said that David wrote this Psalm, but it actually wasn't written by David, how do we reconcile that with the doctrine of inerrancy?

You will need to allow people who do not believe the Bible's clear statements to defend themselves - we will not defend them here.

"If Psalm 110 was NOT written by David, then did Jesus make an error in stating that "David himself calls him …" — If so, then most people might say "yes", but hypothetical questions aren't received well on this site. More appropriate would be "Was Psalm 110 written by David?", since that is a direct objective question asking about a single scripture's meaning (not about implications), which is what this site requires.
It would also simplify things, as most of the citations and commentary could be removed. You could of course then use them in an answer to the question yourself.

Hi @RayButterworth, thank you for your advice. I personally found the argument for Psalm 110 being written about David rather than by David compelling, but I didn't want to state such as an undisputed fact. My question is moreso about Jesus' use of the Psalm under this assumption and how a Christian could reconcile this with such doctrines I listed in my question. Yeah, I wasn't sure how many sources I should have cited reading, as this is my first post on this site, so I thought I should get that all out on the front end, in case someone commments merely with a source I've already read.

Hi @Dottard, I'm open to those who don't believe in the inspiration of the Bible to give their take, but I would think that merely a simple "yes" to my question would summarize their position, as they wouldn't have any need to defend Christian doctrines such as Christology and inerrancy. However, my question is moreso about how a Christian would reconcile this seeming discrepency.

@Lucas said "my question is moreso about how a Christian would reconcile this". Questions like that would be more appropriate in Christianity.SE. Hermeneutics.SE is for questions about the text itself. ¶⁠And don't be put off by this reception; it takes some time to learn how things are supposed to work here. If you haven't already, read the Tour and questions about the site.

@RayButterworth, ah, I see. You are right. Thank you. I'll throw this question up over there then.

Incarnation and inerrancy:
Your question of whether Jesus could have been mistaken in attributing the Psalm to David if David was not the actual author brings us to the mystery of the Incarnation: Jesus was both fully human and fully divine. As a human, Jesus increased in wisdom (Luke 2:52). He did not know the day or the hour of His return (Mark 13:32). Yet, as God, He knew all things (John 16:30). How these two natures coexisted in Jesus is a profound mystery.
When speaking of the doctrine of inerrancy, it affirms that the Bible, in its original manuscripts, is without error. This doctrine is based on God’s perfection and truthfulness. If God is perfect and cannot lie, then His Word, as originally given, must also be truthful and without error.
Psalm 110:
The Expositor's Bible Commentary actually touches on this:

It may freely be admitted that there are instances in our Lord’s references to the Old Testament in which He speaks from the point of view of His hearers in regard to it; but these are cases in which
nothing turned on the question whether that point of view was correct
or not. Here everything turns on it; and to maintain that, in so
important a crisis, He based His arguments on an error comes
perilously near to imputing fallibility to Him as our teacher. Most of
recent writers who advocate the view in question would recoil from
such a consequence; but their position is divided from it by a thin
line. Whatever the limitations of our Lord’s human knowledge, they did
not affect His authority in regard to what He did teach; and the
present writer ventures to believe that He did teach that David in
this psalm calls Messiah his Lord.

The doctrine of inerrancy does not necessarily mean that every statement in the Bible is factually accurate. For example, the Bible records lies told by individuals, but it does not endorse those lies. Similarly, the Bible may record cultural understandings or beliefs of the time that we now know are not scientifically accurate, but it does not endorse those beliefs as ultimate truth.
In the case of Psalm 110, if it turns out that David was not the author, this would not necessarily mean that Jesus made an error or that the doctrine of inerrancy is undermined. It could mean that Jesus was speaking from the cultural and religious understanding of His time, which attributed the Psalm to David. Jesus' purpose in referring to the Psalm was not to make a statement about its authorship, but to use it to reveal truths about Himself.

Hi Jason, thank you for taking the time to share. Your answer is both helpful and thought-provoking. I wonder if the kenosis theory (though I'm not insinuating that is what you are espousing) could be a helpful articulation of what could be at play here. And regarding your take on the doctrine of inerrancy, I know that "divine accomodationism" is something theologians have termed for what it sounds like you're describing.

What I'm having difficuty with still is how Jesus seems to use Davidic authorship of the Psalm not merely as an incidental accommodationism but as the basis of His argument, and how in Mark and Luke he doesn't seem to state Davidic authorship as being theoretical but as a fact. Even that Expositor's commentator seems to feel that it could be detrimental if the Psalm was not actually written by David, saying that if "[Jesus] based His arguments on an error", it "comes perilously near to imputing fallibility to Him as our teacher."

Psalm 110:1 - (LXX 109:1) τῷ Δαυιδ ψαλμός εἶπεν ὁ κύριος τῷ κυρίῳ μου κάθου ἐκ δεξιῶν μου ἕως ἂν θῶ τοὺς ἐχθρούς σου ὑποπόδιον τῶν ποδῶν σου
ΤωΔΑΥΙΔΨΑΛΜΟCΕΙΠΕΝΟΚΥΡΙΟCΤωΚΥΡΙωΜΟΥΚΑΘΟΥΕΚΔΕξΙωΝΜΟΥΕωCΑΝΘωΤΟΥCΕΧΘΡΟΥCCΟΥΥΠΟΔΙΟΝΤωΝΠΟΔωΝCΟΥ
And the LORD said dance.
I think it’s about David because of the placements of the endings ω and C. David is  κυριοω and the LORD is κύριος
At other times I think it’s still about David because it was translated wrong. A song of David to the LORD. My LORD, sit at my right hand until I make my enemies your footstool.
At even more other times I think it’s still about David because the MT corrected the LXX because of the MT.
Other times I think what would stop someone from writing in the third person vocative case to begin with?

You say "I think it’s about David because of the placements of the endings ω and C." There is no "C" in Greek - your transliteration mistakes ς, the letter s, for c.

Yes there is friend. The Greek alphabet at the time of early Christianity was written in all capital letters, and sigma is always written as a capital C. That’s two differences between it and modern Greek. The lowercase alphabet was much later invented because of Christianity, I’ve  heard.

Your application is an anachronism. Writing s with a capital c does not change how it is going to be pronounced. Under your misguided theory, the letter s would disappear from the Greek language.

The alpha is slightly different too. It almost at times looks like a Λ if you don’t zoom in close. The specific letter alpha changes shape a few times throughout the centuries. You will find the sacred name abbreviation ΘC everywhere in the early NT. The nomina sacra. It’s also always used to abbreviate the name of Jesus Christ

The ending of a word in Greek changes what grammar case it is in so the sentence can somehow be made sense of about what verb relates to what noun and such

I wrote it in Ancient Greek of the first century and LXX. However this Greek alphabet on my iPhone does not have the correct capital omega ω that you would see in the texts. The capital and lowercase omega are identical. Lowercase alphabet doesn’t exist yet in the context of it.

There’s no spaces between letters, no commas or periods in sentences, and everything is capital letters

Let's stay focused on your ignorance of the Greek alphabet. The letter you claim is "C" is the sigma, Σ which is only written as C at the end of a word. Regardless of how it is written, is still the 18th letter of the alphabet not the third. It is "s" not "c." There is no ci n the Greek alphabet then or now.

Greek alphabet 2000 years ago wrote sigma  as a C

Only at the end of a word and it did not change how it was pronounced.

No, 2000 years ago it was the only form of sigma. Used anywhere in the word.

@ReturnOfRoamer thank you for sharing your input. You wrote, "Other times I think what would stop someone from writing in the third person vocative case to begin with?" Carson's commentary on Matthew sugggests the third person approach as a possibility, writing, "That Psalm 110 is about the king makes sense only if the superscription is ignored. If David is indeed the author, as both the psalm’s superscription and Jesus insist, then either the psalm deals with some figure other than David or else David, caught up in high prophetic vision, is writing about himself in the third person."

However, I believe this is presumptuous to not allow the superscription "of David" to mean about David. And as Dr. Michael Brown points out, "Very farfetched is the view of Nachmanides (in his classic Barcelona debate of 1263), followed recently by Tovia Singer, namely, that David wrote this psalm for his court poets to recite about him. This not only sounds strange, it could well be called egotistical." (Answering Jewish Objections to Jesus, Vol. 3, note 288)
